# How can Cassava error include line number

Tags: haskell

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava

I instantiate `FromField` and call `fail` if needed. So when I `decode`, how do I get the resulting error message to have the **line#** of the CSV where the error is being reported?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like the [`cassava-megaparsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-megaparsec-2.0.4) package provides alternative decoding functions for Cassava with better error messages.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Out of curiosity I've just tried `cassava-megaparsec` and it seems like it will give the character offset of the place where the error is, but not the line number. Which might be sufficient for the @thirsty.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this by parsing each row individually:

```hs
-- | Produce an error with a 0-based index of a row upon parsing failure
decodeWithIndex ::
     FromRecord b
  => DecodeOptions
  -> HasHeader
  -> ByteString
  -> Either String (V.Vector b)
decodeWithIndex opts hasHeader content = do
  rs :: V.Vector Record <- decodeWith opts hasHeader content
  V.mapM parseRecordWithIndex $ V.indexed rs
  where
    parseRecordWithIndex (i, r) =
      case runParser (parseRecord r) of
        Left err ->
          Left $ "Failed at row <" ++ show i ++ ">: " ++ show r ++ " with error: " ++ err
        Right v -> pure v
```

#### Full example

##### Some imports and example data:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Csv
import Data.Text (Text)

csvContent :: ByteString
csvContent =
  "Username, Identifier,First name,Last name\n\
  \booker,9012,Rachel,Booker\n\
  \grey,2070,Laura,Grey\n\
  \johnson,4081,Craig,Johnson\n\
  \jenkins,9346,Mary,Jenkins\n\
  \smith,5079,Jamie,Smith\n"
```

##### Matching Haskell data type with a parser:

```hs
data User = User
  { username :: !Text
  , identifier :: !Word
  , firstName :: !Text
  , lastName :: !Text
  } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance FromRecord User where
  parseRecord r = do
    username <- r .!? 0
    identifier <- r .!? 1
    firstName <- r .!? 2
    lastName <- r .!? 3
    pure User {..}

-- | This function should be added in Cassava.
-- I have no clue why anyone would use `(.!)`
(.!?) :: FromField a => Record -> Int -> Parser a
(.!?) r ix =
  case r V.!? ix of
    Nothing -> fail $ "Record doesn't have enough elements at index: " ++ show ix
    Just f -> parseField f
```

##### Decoding functions

```hs
regularDecoder :: Either String (V.Vector User)
regularDecoder = decodeWith defaultDecodeOptions HasHeader csvContent

indexedDecoder :: Either String (V.Vector User)
indexedDecoder = decodeWithIndex defaultDecodeOptions HasHeader csvContent
```

##### Output

When there are no errors both will work in the same way:

```hs
λ> either putStrLn (mapM_ print) regularDecoder
User {username = "booker", identifier = 9012, firstName = "Rachel", lastName = "Booker"}
User {username = "grey", identifier = 2070, firstName = "Laura", lastName = "Grey"}
User {username = "johnson", identifier = 4081, firstName = "Craig", lastName = "Johnson"}
User {username = "jenkins", identifier = 9346, firstName = "Mary", lastName = "Jenkins"}
User {username = "smith", identifier = 5079, firstName = "Jamie", lastName = "Smith"}
λ> either putStrLn (mapM_ print) indexedDecoder
User {username = "booker", identifier = 9012, firstName = "Rachel", lastName = "Booker"}
User {username = "grey", identifier = 2070, firstName = "Laura", lastName = "Grey"}
User {username = "johnson", identifier = 4081, firstName = "Craig", lastName = "Johnson"}
User {username = "jenkins", identifier = 9346, firstName = "Mary", lastName = "Jenkins"}
User {username = "smith", identifier = 5079, firstName = "Jamie", lastName = "Smith"}
```

However, if we make the input malformed by deleting the `identifier` for `Mary Jenkins` then we get two distinct errors:

```hs
λ> either putStrLn (mapM_ print) regularDecoder
parse error (Failed reading: conversion error: expected Word, got "Mary" (Failed reading: takeWhile1)) at "\nsmith,5079,Jamie,Smith\n"
λ> either putStrLn (mapM_ print) indexedDecoder
Failed at row <3>: ["jenkins","Mary","Jenkins"] with error: expected Word, got "Mary" (Failed reading: takeWhile1)
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it better to somehow give your record-level error message "Record doesn't have enough elements at index: "? I would just simplify it to "Record doesn't have enough elements" with the line#. This way the problem is pin-pointed without confusion.

Comment: Row number is not the same thing as line number, though.

Comment: Putting `when (length r /= 4) $ fail "Record doesn't have enough elements"` as the first line in the `do` of `parseRecord r = do` does the trick I guess...

Comment: I now have this as first line of `do`: `checkFieldCount r 4`

Comment: `checkFieldCount :: Record -> Int -> Parser ()`

Comment: `checkFieldCount r n = when (length r /= n) $ fail $ "Record must have exactly " <> show n <> " fields" `

Comment: @DanielWagner Error on a particular line does not make sense in the context of a CSV, because a field can contain multi-line characters. If the literal line number in the file was the intent in the question, then it should have been:  "How do I report a span of lines where the field that fails parsing is located". In any case, ability to report a row number will usually be good enough because it will match closely the line number in most cases, since more often than not in CSV files there is only one row per line and very short header

Comment: @thirsty I didn't care about the number of fields in rows, since that was not the actual question you were asking. But sure, protecting against the correct vector length is a good approach. I'd also suggest using `decodeByNameWith` and checking the length of the `Header` for the expected number of elements in each row

Comment: Error on a particular line makes sense when your editor has a "jump to line" command but no "jump to CSV row" command -- which, I would guess, describes the majority of editors.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done with cassava's current API. If you must have it, you will have to fork it or write your own library.